# Getting IP address and port number from http.Client

Tags: go

I'm making a http Client that keeps an open connection. I want to get the IP address of the client made. I know that I can give it its own ip address by using transport's Dial function. However is there a way that I can obtain its address after declaring the client?

```
var tr= &http.Transport{DisableKeepAlives:false}
var client = http.Client{Transport :tr}
```

Comment: Golang's `http.Client` keeps a connection pool to make requests. A tcp connection is not made until you're actually ready to make the request.

Comment: So if for example I do client.Get("www.google.com") how will i be able to get the connection information.

Comment: `http.Client` doesn't expose the connection itself. If you want to be able to grab the connection you'll need to use `net.Conn`. From the looks of it, `http.Transport` Dial gives you the network and the address so you could probably work off that as it should only Dial when the request is made.

Comment: @Socome23: you don't (well, you could log it form the Dialer, but you can't definitively link it to the client's call). Unless you set it yourself, the ip address used is determined by the OS, so you should be able to determine what it will be at any point.